# Python code to extract single/multiple attachments(.pdf/.png) from .msg file

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, msg

I have a master folder containing 10-15 .msg files.

Each file may or maynot have attachments either in pdf or png format.

Is there any python code to extract those attachments .

P.S i already tried pywin32..it is specific to just windows.
I am looking to run my code in linux/ubuntu terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the package [extract_msg](https://pypi.org/project/extract-msg/) as shown below in the form of a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (without looping all mail files, without considering overwriting due to duplicate filenames,  etcetera).

```
import extract_msg

with extract_msg.openMsg('Mail.msg') as msg:
    for attm in msg.attachments:
        file = attm.save()
```